# Database script not executing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, database-schema, database-scripts

In my **sqlserver 2008 R2**
I have a database script which generate successfully, but when I am trying to execute that script its only shows **Executing query** message and nothing happen. 
I had waited at-lest 10 minutes for result but force fully I have to stop executing that query.

> Note: All other queries are working normally, but only database script is not executing as explained above.

I doesn't know what's going on...

```
More details: This thisng is not happen on particular DataBase, it is make problem to all the database of my sqlserver.
```

Even no any single DataBase's script working, as explain below.
Its being remain to show **Executing queries**...

Comment: If you leave it long enough, it might finish (in which case it's just a lack of suitable indexes/poorly designed query). Perhaps it's a locking problem.

Comment: Its, still executing and my Db is not much larger, only 15 tables are there and not much table value...

Comment: Could you please post the query/details of any indexes/any isolation level settings you know of to help any future answerers?

Comment: On terminate query its shows following details "Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed." I hope it will be use full...

Comment: It seems like some major problem in sqlserver

Comment: Please post the **full** error. There might be multiple. You are probably seeing blocking due to a database being locked. Does the script run to completion immediately after you have restarted SQL Server?

Comment: See this question is transfer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461057/database-script-not-executing-in-sql-server-2008/14461329#comment20142461_14461329