# Database script not executing in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

In my SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a database script which generates successfully, but when I am trying to execute that script it only shows Executing query message and nothing happen. 
I had waited at-least 10 minutes for result but force fully I have to stop executing that query.

> Note: All other queries are working normally, but only database script is not executing as explained above

I don't know what's going on...

> More details: This thing is not happening on particular DataBase, it is a problem on all the database of my SQL Server.

lets see it by example.
In SQL Server 2008 R2, I have following type of script.

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [BillingApplication]    Script Date: 01/22/2013 17:42:04 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'BillingApplication')
BEGIN
CREATE DATABASE [BillingApplication] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'BillingApplication', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\BillingApplication.mdf' , SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'BillingApplication_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\BillingApplication_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
END
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [BillingApplication].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET ARITHABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET  DISABLE_BROKER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET  READ_WRITE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET RECOVERY FULL
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET  MULTI_USER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET DB_CHAINING OFF
GO
EXEC sys.sp_db_vardecimal_storage_format N'BillingApplication', N'ON'
GO
USE [BillingApplication]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tbCustBill]    Script Date: 01/22/2013 17:42:07 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tbCustBill]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
                    -- And continue the entire script
```

Now as I had seen in **SQL Server Profiler** than the execution till following code work perfectly.

```
    ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
        GO
```

And on the the next line executing become stop.
I don't know what's going on....
On force full stop of execution its generate error as below

> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

So, that's it may be some SQL Sever configuration problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to ensure you can place an exclusive lock on the database to change this setting. Even though you just created the database you may have established more than one connection to it. Make sure you disable IntelliSense in Management Studio, that you have no other windows connected to this database, and that you switch context to another database. Then set the database to single user, make your changes, and set it back:

```
USE master;
GO

ALTER DATABASE BillingApplication SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

ALTER DATABASE BillingApplication SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF;
GO

ALTER DATABASE BillingApplication SET DISABLE_BROKER;    
GO

... other changes ...

ALTER DATABASE BillingApplication SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

If this still waits then you may be waiting on some very large transaction to roll back, and you can check in another window what you are waiting for by looking at `sys.dm_exec_requests` and/or `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`.

Though, if you are creating the database, why do you think you need to explicitly disable broker? It's not enabled by default...

Comment: So did you try removing the `SET DISABLE_BROKER` line from your script? Did it work then? Did you try what I posted?

Comment: I had tried both, I had removed Broker line and also made changes as u had said. but it still gives me error.....and show msg "Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%."
Remember that I had scripted the DB, and threw that I had not make any changes...

Comment: So you set the database to `SINGLE_USER` and it still sat there executing query? Did you open another window and see what that spid is waiting on or who it is blocked by in `sys.dm_exec_requests`? Could you share that information with us?

Comment: Which info u need from sys.dm_exec_requests?

Comment: You may find a number in `blocking_session_id` (so then go find out what that session is doing) and also you should see what `wait_type` and `last_wait_type` say.

Comment: blocking_session_id = 53, wait_type  = LCK_M_X , last_wait_type = LCK_M_X, this all I get from that table. (this data  are in last to second row)

Comment: And what is session 53 doing? `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(53);`?

Comment: Session id = 53 is not avalible

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that means. Is your query still waiting or did you stop it? What shows in `sys.dm_exec_requests` for session_id 53? How about `sys.dm_exec_sessions`? Help me help you here.

Comment: No, I need you to be able to troubleshoot what else is running on your system. I'm trying to give you pointers on where to look but I can't sit here all day hunting and pecking with you.

Comment: Else nothing is running in my system....
The executing is still continue more than 20 min passed....

Comment: If nothing is running on your system then why is your query blocked by session_id = 53? Please find out what session 53 is doing. I can't tell you what it's doing but you have all the information in front of you.

Comment: the state of session = 53 is sleeped, and much more we can solve this on TeamViewer...

Answer (score 0):

You have

> ALTER DATABASE [BillingApplication] SET  DISABLE_BROKER

without ane `ON` or `OFF`. Set that and it should work.

---

Nope, that's not it. I'd guess it has something to do with the Service Broker sub-system, but that's not something I'm familiar with. Hopefully someone else who knows that system can answer this...\